# Is duplicating an ArrayList or using a ListIterator faster when trying to manipulate an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, listiterator

I have multiple `ArrayList`s with lots of data and I need to manipulate the data quickly and efficiently. My code currently makes a duplicate of the original `ArrayList` so that I can make changes (avoiding `ConcurrentModificationException`). This approach seems somewhat inefficient.

I've looked into `ListIterator`s and they seem much more "clean" and efficient. I ran a quick test to see which is actually faster and it seems duplicating the original `ArrayList` may be faster. Is this true or is my test flawed in some way? If it is true, does it only hold for smaller `ArrayList`s?

The test I ran is below:

```
long startTime, stopTime;

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<String> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> a3 = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a1.add(Integer.toString(i));
    a2.add(Integer.toString(i));
    a3.add(Integer.toString(i));
}

array.add(a1);
array.add(a2);
array.add(a3);

startTime = System.nanoTime();

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayCopy = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<String> line = array.get(i);
    arrayCopy.add(i, new ArrayList<>(line.size()));
    for (int j = 0; j < line.size(); j++) {
        arrayCopy.get(i).add(j, line.get(j));
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.get(j).size(); i++) {
        if (array.get(j).get(i).equals("2")) {
            arrayCopy.get(j).add(i, "1.5");
        }
    }
}

stopTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

System.out.println(arrayCopy.get(0));
System.out.println(arrayCopy.get(1));
System.out.println(arrayCopy.get(2));

System.out.println(stopTime);

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> brray = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<String> b1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> b2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> b3 = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    b1.add(Integer.toString(i));
    b2.add(Integer.toString(i));
    b3.add(Integer.toString(i));
}

brray.add(b1);
brray.add(b2);
brray.add(b3);

startTime = System.nanoTime();
for (ArrayList<String> s : brray) {
    ListIterator<String> i = s.listIterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        if (i.next().equals("1")) {
            i.add("1.5");
        }
    }
}

stopTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

System.out.println(b1);
System.out.println(b2);
System.out.println(b3);

System.out.println(stopTime);
```

Running the code five times gave me times (in nano seconds) of `73307, 46916, 77705, 76606 and 82470` for the duplicating method and `307888, 319984, 304590, 363235 and 280032` for the `ListIterator` method.

Comment: Where is the original data coming from? Do you do any type of parsing? You could make the "copies" and do some "manipulation" while you loop through and initialize your initial array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: One difference would be that if you add an element via the list iterator you'll iterate over that as well, i.e. you have 6 instead of 5 iterations.

Comment: @gonzo Yeah I do some parsing but it's minimal. I could create another ArrayList when I'm doing that but it'll simply reduce to another add method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure without looking at their implementation but from some tests:

For larger sizes, ListIterator will beat out ArrayList method.

For smaller sizes, just creating the ListIterator takes longer than the ArrayList method.

Also, time benchmarks are kind of questionable, because there is a lot more to it than just the program itself. Especially those in the 10^(-3) seconds.

Comment: Yeah I code a ListIterator approach for my situation and the difference is quite noticeable. With my small test up ahead, creating the ListIterator was what caused it to take so long.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in to ArrayList implementation. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.add%28java.lang.Object%29

You need much more items to make a good test. The ArrayList uses array inside and creates by default an array of 10 item. So your add/get etc. methodes have a complexity of O(1). You can look into listIterator method. It use the same approach. I guess, you don't need to use iterator when you use ArrayList explicitly but when you use List interface, because the implementation can be different.